# Prove that the following integral is zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to prove that the following integral is zero:

$$
 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \left\{\cot \theta \,\tan ^{-1}(\cot \theta) \right.
$$
$$
\left.-\cot \theta\, \tan ^{-1}\left[\frac{\csc \theta \left(R^2 \cos \theta -r_1 \sqrt{R^2-r_1^2 \sin ^2\theta}\right)}{R^2-r_1^2}\right] \right\} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
$$

I expect this integral to be zero both due to the physical context it comes from and because I've computed it in a numerical way. But I would like to have a rigorous mathematical proof.

All variables are real and the only assumption is that $r_1<R$.

I've tried to think of symmetry considerations, but I was not able to prove it.

Comment: How do you define cot(pi) here?

Comment: I understand there is a problem for $\theta=\pi$. To my purposes it is not important. Feel free to make whatever (reasonable) assumption in order to answer.

Comment: Let the integrand be $f(\theta)$. You should find that $f(\theta+\pi)=-f(\theta)$.

Comment: Thank your for the hint, but unfortunately it is not the case.